# How to create list with properties from another list in Spring?

Tags: java

Assume two classes: A, B. Where A has a property of Class B.

```
class A {
   private B b;
}
```

In my xml, I have a bean with the list of different B.

I want to construct a list of A, with properties as B, in the same order.

PS: I can also do the reverse process. First creating list of beans of A with defined properties. And then creating list of B from this. (If you have a solution in this case, it will also work)

Comment: can you elaborate more and add code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use Java Stream.Some code like below:

```
listB.stream().map(b -> new A(b)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```